# How to solve this TypeScript Generics error?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to make a function that receives `string | undefined` and also returns `string | undefined`. This was my first approach:

```
sanitizeName: (name: string | undefined): string | undefined => {
  return name?.replace(...)
},
```

However, when I call this function with a string argument, I know for sure it will also return a `string`, but now the type is `string | undefined` and I need an extra existence check.

What I tried is assigning a generic `T` that is `string | undefined`, and it is the parameter and returned type:

```
sanitizeName: <T extends string | undefined>(name: T): T => {
  return name?.replace(...)
},
```

In my head, this should work: if the function receives undefined, it returns undefined. If it receives a string, it returns a string.

But I got this error:

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'string | undefined' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | undefined'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'undefined' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

Why is that? How can I get the desired behavior (`string` returns `string`, `undefined` returns `undefined`)?

Comment: Use an overload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to build a similar function, it seems that typescript cannot infer the subtype of `T` this way, so I had to do something like this:

```js
function sanitizeName(name: string): string;
function sanitizeName(name: undefined): undefined;
function sanitizeName(name: string | undefined): string | undefined {
  return ...
}
```

Learn more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) about Function Overloads

Answer (score 1):

```
<T extends string | undefined>
```

means that `T` **extends** `string | undefined`. That is, `T` could be `string`, `undefined`, **or any subtype thereof**. Suppose somebody wrote:

```
type Color = "blue" | "green"; // a subtype of string
const color: Color = ...;
const x = sanitizeName(color);
```

the compiler infers

```
function sanitizeName<Color>(name: Color): Color
```

and therefore assumes that `sanitizeName`, which was passed a `Color`, will return a `Color`. But `sanitizeName` probably doesn't do that.

And that's why you can't assign `string` to `T`. `T` could be a subtype of string, such as `Color`, that doesn't admit arbitrary strings.